# Disable multiple statements in PHP PDO

Tags: php, security, pdo

Is there a way to disable multiple statement queries in PDO? A method that works with all the drivers supported?

Alternatively, is there any well known filter that detect multiple statements in a string?

I know that prepared statements can better prevent SQL injection risks, there are reasons why I can't use them in this case.

Comment: Regexes aside or simulated queries aside, I think that you still should use prepared statements, else bobby may get angry. http://bobby-tables.com/ , http://bobby-tables.com/php.html . Why can't you use them? can you please explain the background behind that?

Comment: Trust me, the whole scenario is really too complex to explain in a few sentences here. Bobby won't get angry. Extreme case just to give an example: let's say a user is allowed to write in a form and execute an arbitrary query. There is no parameters here i.e. no prepared statements approach possible, right? Would it be possible to prevent multiple statements?

Comment: If a user is allowed to write anything, why would they care about multiple statements? Why not to write anything they want in that single statement they are allowed?

Comment: As I said, it's just a stupid and extreme example to show you that sometimes you can't use prepared statement. Anyway, I know the risks related to the SQL injection attacks; my question is a very clean and simple programming question: is it possible to disable multiple statements in PDO or filter them?

Comment: What are the reasons you can't use prepared statements?

Comment: Filtering might follow the jungle route of finding the leftmost index of a semi colon after canonicalization. If it succeeds, pick only the part up to that index from the left, else take it all. You seem to be aware of injection and so, You will know what to do ;-) Good luck ... I am long out of the PDO business, so only a content filter suggestion from my side.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? You have tagged the question as security, what does that have to do with your question?

Comment: @Dilettant thanks for the comment, if I don't find anything I'll write something by myself. I hoped to find a PDO setting (I remember there was a way to do it for a particular PHP db driver, don't remember which one) but I think there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to disable multiple statement queries, at least for PDO MySQL, you can do it by using the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_MULTI_STATEMENTS constant [1,2]; the constant exists as of PHP 5.5.21 and PHP 5.6.5.

I have looked for an equivalent for PostgreSQL, SQLite and MS SQL Server but I haven't found it. However, according to my tests, PDO PostgreSQL and SQLite don't allow multiple statement queries, while pdo_sqlsrv does. I haven't found official documentation about this, though, so it could depend on my driver version or other factors.

References:

[1] http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

[2] https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68424

Answer (score 2):

You are barking the wrong tree.

Multiple statement is not a synonym for SQL injection. It's just a subset, a very small one, out of zilliards other possible ways to exploit an injection.

Therefore you should protect from injection, not multiple statement. For this, a  query that is sent to database API have to be 100% hardcoded in your script. To achieve that, always substitute all the variables in the query with placeholders.

Comment: I perfectly know it; sometimes it's just not possible, see my comment above.

Comment: Sorry, but I see no logic in your argument.

Comment: Ok, if you don't see the logic forget about the reasons why I need it; my question is a very clean and simple programming question: is it possible to disable multiple statements in PDO or filter them?

Comment: I am sorry, we answer only sensible questions here.

Comment: I am not aware of any rule on SO that prevents to ask/answer a "not sensible" question; any SPECIFIC programming question is allowed. If you don't want to answer just don't do it but don't assume you can change the rules just because you don't like my question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not your personal help desk to satisfy your whims. Its mission is to accumulate the *knowledge* that can be useful by many people. Your question is apparently of no practical value for anyone else.

Comment: You know in advance that my question is of no practical value for anyone else? I am sorry but this is very specious reasoning. Again, if you don't want to answer, just avoid doing it instead of starting a (much useless than my question) discussion. I explicitly said that I knew how SQL injection attacks work.

Comment: @Eugenio: His point is just that it is pointless to do that. The answer to your question is in the last sentence of his answer: `a query that is sent to database API have to be 100% hardcoded in your script`. That's it. Regardless the amount of effort you put to avoid "multiple statements", you still will be exposed to possible injections. Hardcode the query manually (extract the query provided by the user and examine it, then CREATE a query from it), do not allow the user to execute queries without checking what he is trying to do.

Comment: @briosheje it's not true. It is in the vast majority of the Web applications but sometimes you might need from the user not only parameters but also SQL commands; anyway, as I said before I don't want to open here a discussion about a topic that would be difficult to explain in a few paragraphs.
What I want to point out is that sometimes on SO I see that people don't get one simple rule: despite the fact that computers understand only 0 and 1, the reality is more fuzzy. I'll give you a couple of examples.

Comment: @briosheje Let's say you get hired to secure an application as fast as possible. Let's say we are talking about tens of thousands of lines you didn't write and rewrite the queries in the proper way (prepared statements, ...) takes weeks. You want, however, take some preliminary steps to fix at least the bigger security holes as soon as possible. In other words, we know that seatbelt + airbag is better, but if you have to choose now between a car having only seatbelt and another without any security system which one would you choose?

Comment: @briosheje another use case: you don't have complete control on the codebase, many people work on it and, despite you tried to do everything in the correct way, you still want to add some additional checks (e.g. prevent multiple statements execution) to  add an additional security layer. This is just security redundancy, why is it perceived as a weird thing here?

Comment: @Eugenio: Again. Stackoverflow is about finding clever solutions to real problems. Your problem is currently a pretty abstract one (we don't have any code to work on), and you're asking us to provide a bad practice solution. Would that work? Of course it will, but is it actually correct to provide a bad practice solution? not sure. My point is that if you need to fix that immediatly then just use a regex. Write your own regex to match the query, be careful because you are vulnerable to tons of injections, then fix it in the **proper way**. Just hardcode. You're just delaying the real issue.

Comment: @briosheje providing at least SOME security as fast as possible IS an example of real problem. If you don't get this it means you have never faced complex situations where time is essential. Security redundancy IS an example of real need. As I said already several times (also in the original question) I KNOW how SQL injection attacks work and I am aware of the risks. Anyway, I've removed the security tag to this question.

Comment: @Eugenio: Thanks for pretending to know that I don't know what I'm talking about :). Anyway, move on then, REGEX is your friend. I can't do more than that apparently, so have fun preventing injections through regexes. Next time, maybe, add all the details you provided in the comments here, they could've been very useful.

Comment: @briosheje I have added an answer (only for MySQL) to this old question; the fact that the request for MYSQL_ATTR_MULTI_STATEMENTS has been done explicitly referring to a Drupal vulnerability (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68424) should highlight that I was not the only one in the PHP community that thought this could improve the security of PHP applications.